# uptime + cpu load average

Tags: linux, rhel, cpu, top, load-average

we have the follwing CPU details

```
more lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                32
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    8
```

uptime show

```
uptime
 07:41:41 up 40 days, 11 min,  2 users,  load average: 17.82, 23.40, 24.73
```

so we have 32 CPU ( Thread(s) per core:    2 )

Regarding the high values of the CPU load average from uptime, 
are these values normal?

load average: 17.82, 23.40, 24.73

Comment: Short answer: it is normal if there are several processes running. It is not, if your machine is (or should be) idle. What processes are running on this CPU? You may check out [this explanation](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html) to get started with load averages meaning.

Comment: so you think the load average isn't normal ?  , but we have 32 CPU , so what is the limit of load average that we say this threshold is the max and any value more then this will point about a problem

Comment: until now I was thinking that if we have 32 CPU ( and actually they 64 ) , then we can accept load average until 64 , am I wrong here ?

Comment: "Normal" depends on what you are doing on the system.

Comment: "Load" is a measure of the length of the run queue. It does not necessarily have anything to do with the CPUs. There is no "CPU load" in the output from `uptime`.

Comment: @yael "I was thinking that if we have 32 CPU ( and actually they 64 ) , then we can accept load average until 64": you are right. Even a higher load *roughly*
till about 85 may be acceptable.

Comment: @yael "so you think the load average isn't normal ?" It is reasonably normal, **if** your server is in use and it runs something. It isn't normal, for example, if you have just started it, it has no connections and it shouldn't be doing anything: in that case, there is some unexpected process which is consuming CPU. But if your server is operating and running something it is supposed to run, your current load is definitely acceptable. Check out the link I provided in the first comment for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a hard one.

If the load average is higher than number of CPUs (for too long), then this is a sign that things are queuing up.

However if they are less, this is not a sign of anything. There can be one process, using 100% of a CPU, that is not getting its work done.

On the other hand, if you have many low priority batch processes, with no real time deadline. This can cause the load average to go up, but not affect the performance of the machine.

So the short answer is, it depends.

In this case:

I see no cause for alarm, if and only if, the system is doing useful work. However there may be a single (un-parallelised) task, that is not keeping up with its work load, load-average will not tell you about this.

Comment: so regarding my case we have ( 64 cpu's ) because Thread(s) per core:    2 , so the max load average that we get is 25 , and CPU are 64 , so can we say that for now load average is ok?

Comment: Did I say that? — I have added another paragraph.

Comment: @yael As said in the answer, you must know the processes that are currently running in the machine: if «the system is doing useful work», for example it is running a webserver with multiple connections, then it is all right. Otherwise, there may be something undesired which is using the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the commands below.

**First method**

Find out the number of processor configured in the host:

```
    cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i processor| wc -l
```

Suppose the output we got is `4`: then, a load average up to 4 is OK. If it goes beyond 4 then there is an issue.

Note: the (acceptable) load average directly depends on the number of core processor configured.

**Second method**

You can use the script below to find if the load average is fine or not:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    processor_count=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i processor| wc -l`
    echo $processor_count

    w| awk 'NR==1 {print $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=" ";print $0}'| sed -r "s/^\s+//g"|awk -F ":" '{print $2}'| awk -v pr="$processor_count" -F "," '{if (($1 > pr) || ($2 > pr) || ($3 > pr)){print "Load average is high and its above 100% of utilization"}else{print "load average is fine"}}'
```

Comment: what is  w meaning in the script ?

Comment: @yael `w` is a command. He could have used `uptime` here too and remove the `NR==1` condition.

Comment: if you execute script it will find whether load average is fine on the server or not

Comment: @Kusalananda yes agreed

Comment: Note though that the load may be high due to _other reasons_ than CPU congestions. Having multiple processes waiting on a disk will also give you high load even though the CPUs may be under-utilized.